# Running aws RDS MySQL in 3 AZs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, availability-zone

I'm planning to run MySQL RDS. 
My question is Is it possible to run MySQL in 3 availability zones? Or is it only limited to 2 AZs. If it's running in 3AZs does it mean I get better redundancy compare with running in two AZs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the RDS Multi-AZ High Availability feature[1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html) you can only have one stand-by replica:

> In a Multi-AZ deployment, Amazon RDS automatically provisions and maintains a synchronous standby replica in a different Availability Zone. The primary DB instance is synchronously replicated across Availability Zones to a standby replica to provide data redundancy, eliminate I/O freezes, and minimize latency spikes during system backups. Running a DB instance with high availability can enhance availability during planned system maintenance, and help protect your databases against DB instance failure and Availability Zone disruption.

This is *only* a failover solution -- you can't use the standby for load balancing.

You can create additional Read Replicas[2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html) that cover other availability zones and can be used to horizontally scale read traffic. But there are two caveats:

- Unlike the standby, RDS cannot automatically fail over to a read replica when the primary DB goes down. You would need to implement this yourself using other tools like Route53.
- Read replicas use asynchronous replication, so they may lag behind the master. You need to determine if this is acceptable in your failover scenario.